# Best way to do a Count in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am not so good in TSQL and i want to write a report in this manner:

input: Table A

```
ID   Company Product  Flag
1    A        Car        Y
2    A        Van        N
3    B        Van        Y
4    A        Part       N
```

Output

```
Company     Y     N
A           1     2
B           1     0
```

if one can assist in TSQL...

Comment: Title is wrong.it should be "Pivot in Sql server"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Company
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN Flag = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Y
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN Flag = 'N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS N
FROM tab
GROUP BY Company
```

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for conditional aggregation:

```
select company,
       sum(case when flag = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) as num_y,
       sum(case when flag = 'N' then 1 else 0 end) as num_n
from t
group by company;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CASE` expressions (the people call it "*conditional aggregation*") to count the flagged products per customer like this (which will ignore a record when the `Product` column is empty):

```
SELECT Company
  , COUNT(CASE Flag WHEN 'Y' THEN Product END) AS Y
  , COUNT(CASE Flag WHEN 'N' THEN Product END) AS N
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Company;
```

Or you can use this PIVOT query, which is a short form of writing the above:

```
SELECT Company, Y, N
FROM (SELECT Company, Product, Flag FROM YourTable) AS src
PIVOT (COUNT(Product) FOR Flag IN (Y, N)) AS pvt;
```

Answer (score 0):

use case when

```
    select company,
   sum(case when flag='Y' then 1 else 0 end) as Y,
   sum(case when flag='N' then 1 else 0 end) as N from tabe_data
   group by company
```